# radar chart from duration (HH:mm:ss)

Tags: excel

I want to create a radar chart that show how many times ranges 2-3 hours happened, the same for 3-4 hours, 4-5 hours,..etc

I have a column in excel spreadsheet that has :
hh:mm:ss

Please your help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? `COUNTIFS()` should work.  How is your data presented?

Comment: Thanks, I used COUNTIFS, it worked.